# Publish my Google Play statistics automatically

Tags: statistics, play-store

Owning several popular Android apps, researchers often ask me for my statistics, which I am happy to provide since they contain no confidential information. Problem: It takes half an hour every time to export the data manually and upload it to DataHub.

So, I am looking for a solution to make this automatic or at least faster.

- Free for me
- Free for people who want to download the data, no registration required
- The destination for the files can be anywhere, but open-minded platforms like DataHub or GitHub preferred. Obviously, a specially-crafted platform that allows visitors to explore the statistics online before downloading would be the best, but I guess it is too much to ask for :-)

[image: Download Google Play statistics]

Answer (score 2):

Far from perfect, but I just wrote a script that downloads your statistics from command line:

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/publish-my-google-play-statistics

Drawbacks:

- Not automatic. You have to manually click an OAuth authorization.
- After download you still have to upload the files to Github or FTP using another command line.